# Windows Security pop ups 3 times and then I get a blank page

Tags: windows-authentication, https

on my web application I am using HTTPS. When I try to access the site inside Web application server the website will display the window security popup and after attempting to log in 3 times, it show a blank page.

However the site runs just fine on WFE. I can login and see the site.
I am running the servers in a VM.

In App Server I have checked the following:

```
- url of the site exists in the trusted sites in IE
- enhanced security is disabled in the server
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs because Windows Server 2003 SP1 (and every Windows release since) includes a new security feature named loopback check functionality. By default, loopback check functionality is turned on in Windows Server 2003 SP1, and the value of the DisableLoopbackCheck registry entry is set to 0 (zero).

Note The loopback check functionality is stored in the following registry subkey:
**HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\DisableLoopbackCheck**

I recommend Method #1 in the Resolution section on this page:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/926642/error-message-when-you-try-to-access-a-server-locally-by-using-its-fqd

(Create the Local Security Authority host names that can be referenced in an NTLM authentication request)

Comment: disableloopbackcheck is set already to 1. I switched back to 0 then back to 1 and restarted my computer, still did not help.

Comment: I would not recommend using the disable loopbackcheck; instead try method #1 in the link I provided.